# jQuery, form tag bug?

Tags: jquery

I have this internal webpage with a mix of jquery, javascript and perl. The webpage works fine at the moment. I was thinking of using the serialize() to make it easier for me to collect the variable/values to pass on since I am doing it manually.

However, once I started putting the coding `<form id="something"> </form>`, none of my pages work as it did before. It looks once i submit, the webpage is refreshed back to the beginning of the site.

What is doing this? how to prevent this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a jQuery bug, it's how HTML works.  If you don't have a URL in the form tag, it POSTs to itself (thus refreshing the page).  If you POST the form via AJAX, you can use one of the following methods to stop the form from reloading the page.

You can prevent the default form action when it's submitted:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Or you can point the form tag to `javascript:void(0)`:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);">
```

I suggest you use `preventDefault()`, but both ways work.